# Step timed out while step is verifying the SSM Agent availability on the target instance(s). SSM Agent on Instances: [i-xxxxxxx] are not functioning

Tags: patch, amazon-ami, aws-ssm

I am working on "Patch an AMI and update an Auto Scaling group" and followed the AWS [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-walk-patch-windows-ami-autoscaling.html) to configure but I am stuck at "Task 3: Create a runbook, patch the AMI, and update the Auto Scaling group" with the below error. To fix it I have added "user data" while starting the instance(`startInstances`). As it's accepting only base64, converted and provided base64(UmVzdGFydC1TZXJ2aWNlIEFtYXpvblNTTUFnZW50Cg==).

I tried to execute with the below user data but both are not working, even I tried to apply a new step with the same commands but failed to patch AMI.

1. Tried the below script:

   `<powershell> powershell.exe -Command Start-Service -Name AmazonSSMAgent </powershell> <persist>true</persist>`
2. Tried to start and restart SSM agent.

   ```
   Restart-Service AmazonSSMAgent
   ```

   base64: `UmVzdGFydC1TZXJ2aWNlIEFtYXpvblNTTUFnZW50Cg==`

YAML sample:

```
mainSteps:
  - name: startInstances
    action: 'aws:runInstances'
    timeoutSeconds: 1200
    maxAttempts: 1
    onFailure: Abort
    inputs:
      ImageId: '{{ sourceAMIid }}'
      InstanceType: m3.large
      MinInstanceCount: 1
      MaxInstanceCount: 1
      SubnetId: '{{ subnetId }}'
      UserData: UmVzdGFydC1TZXJ2aWNlIEFtYXpvblNTTUFnZW50Cg==
```

Still, I am seeing the below error.

```
Step timed out while step is verifying the SSM Agent availability on the target instance(s). SSM Agent on Instances: [i-xxxxxxxx] are not functioning. Please refer to Automation Service Troubleshooting Guide for more diagnosis details.
```

Your suggestion/solutions help me a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have troubleshoot and fixed the issue.

The issue was security group is missing on the instance. To communicate the SendCommand API of SSM Service with SSM agent on instance needs a security group that allows HTTPS port 443. I have attached SG allowing 443 port then the SSM agent can communicate with the EC2 instance.

EC2 instance IAM role should have SSM agent full access policy attached to it.

We might get the same issue when the SSM agent is not running on the EC2 instance, for that we need to provide user-data or add a new step in YAML or JSON on systems manager Documents.

If you are working on a windows instance use the below script to start the SSM agent. If its Linux server uses Linux script/commands.

```
{
  "schemaVersion": "2.0",
  "description": "Start SSM agent on instance",
  "mainSteps": [
    {
      "action": "aws:runPowerShellScript",
      "name": "runPowerShellScript",
      "inputs": {
        "runCommand": [
          "Start-Service AmazonSSMAgent"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```